# Open a custom extension file with a double-click and load the data in the app. The app was built with Python

Tags: python, desktop-application, double-click

I built my first desktop application with Python and used QT Designer to create the GUI. I can save a file with a custom file extension (I used pickle object serialization) and open it from the app with no problem, thus retrieving all the content I saved. However, If I double-click on the saved file (with the custom extension), it perfectly opens the app but no content is shown. Is there a way to get the path of the double-clicked file so that I can pass it through a function and 'tell' my app to retrieve the content from that specific path/file, or an alternative solution?

Comment: You need to process command line arguments

Comment: you have to use `sys.argv` to get filename when you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe `script.py yourfile.ext` - and then it should get filename when you double click file.

Comment: Thank you very much, MadPhysicist and Furas. It worked on Windows but somehow it didn't work when I tested on Mac.